# Feynman lectures, Volume I, chapter 13-4

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometry, derivatives

While reading [Feynman lectures on Physics, volume I, Chapter 13-4](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_13.html), I found following assumption, which I don't understand:

> Then, since $r^2 = \rho^2 + a^2$, $\rho\,d\rho = r\,dr$. Therefore ...

leading to equation 13.17.

Could somebody please explain why is it correct? However I think that it relates to derivation, but I don´t know how.

Comment: This is called [Pythagoras Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_Theorem). Then differentiate the relation.

Comment: [Differential of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function), from wikipedia.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$r^2=\rho^2+a^2 \tag{1}$$

We know that $r$ and $\rho$ are variables while $a$ is a constant.

Differentiate both sides of $(1)$ wrt some arbitrary variable $u$ (because we knew that both $r$ and $\rho$ are variables,their change will depend on some other variables. Thus we can treat them as $r(u)$ and $\rho(u)$) and use the chain rule

$$2r\frac{\rm dr}{\rm du}=2\rho\frac{\rm d\rho}{\rm du}+0$$
$$r\;\frac{\rm dr}{\rm du}=\rho\;\frac{\rm d\rho}{\rm du}\tag{2}$$

Now recall the differential of a function $f(x,y)$ is defined as
$$\rm df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\;\rm dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\;\rm dy$$

Therefore for $r$ its differential is
$$\rm dr=\frac{\rm dr}{\rm du}\;\rm du$$
Now multiply both sides by $r$ to get
$$r\;\rm dr=r\frac{\rm dr}{\rm du}\;\rm du$$
Now substitute $(2)$ to obtain
$$r\;\rm dr=\rho\frac{\rm d\rho}{du}\;\rm du$$
Now use the differential definition again to collapse the above into the required result
$$r\rm \;dr=\rho \rm\; d\rho$$

The chain rule is the reason why in physics we can use the short-cut in $(2)$ by formally "cancelling the $\rm du$ both sides to obtain the result directly"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your and others explanation! I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a change of notation can help: if $f^2(x)=x^2+c$, then (differentiating both sides) $f(x)f'(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mathematical question but still physically relevant.

The point here is that you need to take the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) on both sides with respect to the different variables.

You have the equation $r^2=\rho^2+a^2$ where $r$ and $\rho$ are both variables but $a$ is a constant (Assuming this from the result, since you have not provided enough context.)

You then take the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) of $r$ on the left side and the differential of $\rho$ on the right side and get the required result.

$$2r\rm dr=2\rho \rm d\rho \Rightarrow r\: \rm dr=\rho \: \rm d\rho$$

Answer (score 0):

The result that the gravity emerging from a infinitly extended sheet of matter is independent of the distance ( it´s a uniform gravityfield) from the sheet can be easily seen if we consider the lines of gravity. They are all parallel, so there is no de- or increase with distance from the sheet. 
A problem arises if we consider (in the general relativity theory) the pace of time.